# How to put extras_require in setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, declarative

[setuptools 30.3.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v30-3-0) introduced declarative package config, allowing us to put most of the options we used to pass directly to `setuptools.setup` in `setup.cfg` files. For example, given following setup.cfg:

```
[metadata]
name = hello-world
description = Example of hello world

[options]
zip_safe = False
packages =
  hello_world
install_requires =
  examples
  example1
```

A setup.py containing only

```
import setuptools
setuptools.setup()
```

will do all the right things.

However, I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax for `extras_require`. In `setup` args, it is a dictionary, like

```
setup(extras_require={'test': ['faker', 'pytest']})
```

But I can't figure out the right syntax to use in setup.cfg. I tried reading the docs, but I can't find the correct syntax that setuptools expects for a dictionary there. I tried a few guesses, too

```
[options]
extras_require =
  test=faker,pytest
```

it fails.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./setup.py", line 15, in <module>
    'pylint',
  File "/lib/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
    _install_setup_requires(attrs)
  File "/lib/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 121, in _install_setup_requires
    dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 495, in parse_config_files
    self._finalize_requires()
  File "/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 419, in _finalize_requires
    for extra in self.extras_require.keys():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Reading the code, I'm not 100% sure this is supported, but based on [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508) it seems this should be a supported use case. What am I missing?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It is supported.  You need a config *section*:

```
[options.extras_require]
test = faker; pytest
```

Syntax is documented [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html?highlight=options.extras_require#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files).